# Can Drools be leveraged to run only certain rules based on the input? The input contains the Rule names and related data

Tags: drools, json-rules-engine

Am new to Drools, looking to leverage Drools rules engine to run specific rules provided in the input. Input contains Rule names and the data.

Looking to see which rules engine can be best leveraged in this scenario when there are Rule names filtered.

Comment: This might be possible, but it's not designed to do this so you'll be writing some framework code which will likely cause it to be inefficient. It wouldn't even be necessary if you write your rules to be appropriately exclusive anyway.